# How to generate all the matrices with each entry of binary values in matlab?

Tags: matrices, matlab

Obviously, there are totally $2^{m\times n}$ matrices ($m$ and $n$ is the size of the matrix). I need a command to generate all of them.

Example: for a $1\times 2$ matrix, there are all $4$ possible matrices, $$K=[a_1\ b_1],\ K=[a_1\ b_2],\ K=[a_2\ b_1],\ K=[a_2\ b_2].$$

Comment: Where have you got stuck doing this problem?

Comment: @Paul I don't know the code the generate all the matrices automatically. I can only write them mannually. But it's unpractical when the size of the matrix is large.

Comment: For example for a matrix [a b] with first entry a={1,2} and the second entry b={3,4}, then the command should output [1 3], [1,4], [2,3], [2,4].

Comment: Your heading said banary values. I thought you meant binary values. I don't understand what you want. Are a and b the rows of the matrix [a b] ? But if they are rows, what does [1, 3] mean?

Comment: @Paul   Sorry, let me restate the problem by using a more clear example. Consider a $2\times 2$ matrix, $A=\begin{bmatrix} a11 & a12 \\a21& a22 \end{bmatrix}$. There are 4 entries, $a11, a12, a21, a22$. Each entry has two predefined values. I want a code to generate all the matrices.

Comment: What most programmers do is to let a counter count from 0 to $2^{mn}$,
and for each of these numbers fill the entries by $mn$ times modulo-2 division
where the remainder, 0 or 1, is placed into the next free cell (left-to-right
or right-to-left along the rows if you're programming in hebrew, down-to-up or 
up-to-down along the columns.)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a recursive function:

```
function binaryMatrixGenerator(N,A):
    global S
    if N
        binaryMatrixGenerator(N,[A,0])
        binaryMatrixGenerator(N,[A,1])
    else
        S = [S;A]
```

Then in the command window, call this function (here we use `m=2` and `n=2` as an example):

```
global S; S=[]; m=2; n=2;
binaryMatrixGenerator(m*n,[])
```

Now `S` is a matrix with `2^(m*n)` rows and `m*n` columns, all you need is to reshape every row of `S` into an `m*n` matrix. (Or you can change the function to directly assign an `m*n` matrix to `S`, this depends on how you want to store the matrices.)

---

Ideas behind the recursion: Since every matrix is just a binary string of length `m*n`, all you need is to add one number ($0$ or $1$) at a time, with a total of `m*n` times. Therefore this is basically a binary tree structure with depth `m*n`, which motivates the above recursion.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved. Thank R. J. Mathar and Mengchun Zhang for the inspiring comments.

Use the command 'dec2bin and 'reshape' in matlab can solve my problem.